# Amazon S3 Event Notification not triggering sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have an Amazon S3 Bucket with Event notification setup for `POST` and `Multipart upload completed` and initially we had it set to trigger a Lambda directly but due to error handling concerns we change it to SQS to get the "backout" feature of SQS to easier capture any message in error.

The files are put to S3 from a SFTP server (EC2 instance) and the events are put to SQS in like 99.9% of the cases but ever so often a file is missed...
We can easily spot this as the SQS will in turn trigger a Lambda and the first thing the Lambda does is to rename the file to ".processing" and as soon as the processing s completed the file is moved to another Bucket.

Now and again we find files with the original file name which has not gotten the ".processing" extension and there are no SQS messages or logs that shows that the Lambda has picked them up. This happens like once in a thousand files or something like that...

Files are always transferred the same way to the Bucket but sometimes there are large batches and it seems to happen more frequently in large batches...

What could be the reason some files are not triggering a notification?
Or what can I check to find what could possibly cause this?

Comment: Are you sure you are capturing all the forms of uploads? I would try to use 's3:ObjectCreated:*' event type to capture really everything.

Comment: `s3:ObjectCreated:*` causes problems if there are "resume" or "chunk" behavior on the upload but as all files are uploaded through SFTP and place the same way (AWS Java SDK) into the Bucket they should all be handled the same way for the Event Notification

Comment: For debugging purpose, can you check if "Number of sent messages" to queue and number of AWS lambda invocations is the same?

Comment: @Anders if you are going to insist on not using `s3:ObjectCreated:* ` -- which should not cause any problems -- they only fire when a complete object is available in the bucket -- then you should at least verify via the bucket logs that the objects in question are indeed all being created the same way, as you believe they are.